SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'ip_address' (using password: YES) trying to connect from elastic beanstalk ec2 to RDS
I have an elastic beanstalk ec2 (Amazon Linux 2023) instance and a RDS database (MariaDB 10.11) created inside same region and using same VPC, my databse is accessible only via ssh tunneling,
i have a laravel app deployed in the ec2 with following .env credentials for database :
RDS_HOSTNAME=prod-example-db.dafsfduieeikka0.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
RDS_PORT=3306
RDS_DB_NAME=db_name
RDS_USERNAME=db_username
RDS_PASSWORD=mydbpassword

following aws ebs documentation for deploying laravel app I have modifed a portion of the config/database.php file of laravel as following:
'host' => env('RDS_HOSTNAME', '127.0.0.1'),
'port' => env('RDS_PORT', '3306'),
'database' => env('RDS_DB_NAME', 'forge'),
'username' => env('RDS_USERNAME', 'forge'),
'password' => env('RDS_PASSWORD', ''),

Now i'm getting SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'db_user'@'ip_address' (using password: YES) when i try to visit my site, Can someone tell me what is the problem?
Do i have to create a ssh tunnel from inside the ec2 to the RDS db to allow the connection?

The fact that it is saying Access Denied means that it is successfully connecting to the Amazon RDS database, but the database is rejecting the connection. So, your network configuration and security groups seem to be operating fine. Either you have the wrong database, username or password OR you make Laravel use secure SSL connection while using AWS RDS — Tech.Semicolon. Amazon RDS will reject a connection that is not using SSL.

@JohnRotenstein according to this doc by aws [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mariadb-ssl-connections.html#MariaDB.Concepts.SSLSupport], MaridaDB RDS instances does not require SSL by default, and i haven't turned it on.

@JohnRotenstein also i've been successful on connecting to the RDS database via ssh tunnel from my local machine database client (DBeaver) with the same database credentials (host name, username, password etc)  and the private key for the ec2.

Try to SSH to your EC2 instance and run the command mysql -u db_username -p'mydbpassword' -h prod-example-db.dafsfduieeikka0.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com db_name. Does it allow you to connect successfully?

@EyadBereh yes i can connect to the RDS database from my ec2 terminal with the above command you wrote, i can even execute queries successfully,  But it is still showing access denied when i visit my laravel app from the browser.

LOL! i put single quotes around my password in .env file now seems like the app has connected to the databse. wow i did not know you have to quote your passwords in the .env file. @EyadBereh thank you for your insight which turned my sense on to trying  quotes around the password haha

@MilonHossain you're welcome, brother! Sometimes the solution is just the unexpected thing :D
Anyway, you may not always need to put single quotes around your password unless you have specific characters such as (#) which may cause a part of your password to be treated as a comment. It's always a good practice to use quotes around values of keys inside .env file for this reason.

Glad you got it working! You are welcome to add your own Answer to assist future readers.

Just used quotes around my password in the .env file and this solved my issue.
RDS_PASSWORD='mydbpassword'

Thank you guys.
